# automatic calling of a function of class each 5min

Tags: php, function

is that it is possible to encode PHP script that can call a function of a class X automatically.

eg I have a class with a function LoadAuto RSS (), this latest load information from an RSS feed of CNN website, and I want every 5min after the functions will applelée automatiquement.yat there a solution?

thank you in advance

Comment: 5 minute intervals forever? Use a cron.

Comment: yeah forever, but how do it with cron ? :D

Comment: Look at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857741/run-php-script-every-5-10-minutes-without-cron-perl-etc

Comment: if you are not familiar with cron jobs you might give this website a try https://ifttt.com/recipes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=cnn

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to regularly run a server-side function which updates values in a database, moves files on the server or similar stuff, you want to look into [Cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

If, on the other hand, you want to display new content in a regular time interval to a user who has loaded your website into his or her browser, you are looking for an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)-based solution.

Example cron-job to invoke `/run_me.php` every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -q -O /dev/null http://localhost/run_me.php
```

Comment: Yes, it's UNIX specific.. What system are you on?

Comment: i want to use it in all systems ,now i work with windows, :s 
this is not another method exept cron ?

Comment: Well, do you want server- or client-side behavior? On the client side, it doesn't matter, all modern browsers support AJAX. On the server side, there's usually no need to 'support all systems'. There are ways to do this on Windows, but I'm no Windows server expert I'm afraid..